# a pointer to a shared object is different in different objects which owns it

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I have a problem with sharing a pointer to a shared object. I have one object of type `C` in class `A`, which is sharing a pointer to it with a object of type `B`. Then the object has a thread which is changing the value `val` of object `c` but the changes are not applied to the pointer which is stored in object `b`. Anyone can help me why is it happening?

With `BOOST`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class C {
public:
  C(int _val): val(_val) {

  }

  ~C(){

  }

  void live(){
    while (true){
      val = rand() % 1000;
      std::cout << "val = " << val << std::endl;
    }
  }

  void setVal(int a){

    val = a;
  }

  int getVal(){
    return val;
  }

private:
  int val;
};

class B {
public:
  B(C* _pointer){
    pointer = _pointer;
  }

  void live(){
    while (true);
  }

  ~B(){

  }

  C* pointer;
};

class A {
public:
  A(): c(10), b(&c) {

  }

  void init() {
    t0 = boost::thread(boost::bind(&B::live, b));
    t1 = boost::thread(boost::bind(&C::live, c));
  }

  ~A() {

  }

  boost::thread t0, t1;

  B b;
  C c;
};

void main() {
  A a;
  a.init();

  while (true){
    std::cout << a.b.pointer->getVal() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

with `C++ 11`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class C {
public:
  C(int _val): val(_val) {

  }

  ~C(){

  }

  void live(){
    while (true){
      val = rand() % 1000;
      std::cout << "val = " << val << std::endl;
    }
  }

  void setVal(int a){

    val = a;
  }

  int getVal(){
    return val;
  }

private:
  int val;
};

class B {
public:
  B(C* _pointer){
    pointer = _pointer;
  }

  void live(){
    while (true);
  }

  ~B(){

  }

  C* pointer;
};

class A {
public:
  A(): c(10), b(&c) {

  }

  void init() {
    t0 = std::thread(std::bind(&B::live, b));
    t1 = std::thread(std::bind(&C::live, c));
  }

  ~A() {

  }

  std::thread t0, t1;

  B b;
  C c;
};

void main() {
  A a;
  a.init();

  while (true){
    std::cout << a.b.pointer->getVal() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe boost bind/thread makes a copy of the bound instance?  Easy to check: block copying.

Comment: Side Note: The order of initialization is determined by the order of declarations
Swap `B b; C c` to `C c; B b`;

Comment: @DieterLücking Why side not and not an answer ?

Comment: @DieterLücking I tried it but it did not change anything.

Comment: @perencia b is only taking the address of the member c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed this chunk of code:

```
t0 = boost::thread(boost::bind(&B::live, b));
t1 = boost::thread(boost::bind(&C::live, c));
```

to:

```
t0 = boost::thread(std::bind(&B::live, &b));
t1 = boost::thread(std::bind(&C::live, &c));
```

Probably if you don't use a pointer to object, it will make a copy of that object and then run the thread.

Comment: By default, it should copy but the object 'c' which I have have shared with the pointer is different from what is changing